# Retrieving CoreData entities for an object in relationship set

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a CoreData data model containing relationships like this:

[image]

a product can be found in different shops and a shop contains several products.

What I try to achieve using a predicate in NSFetchRequest is to get all products entities for a shop entity.

I know that I may get products for shop.products but I need a FectchResquest for my collectionView.

Do you have an idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you just need to pull all the products for which any shop has the id you are looking for:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY self.shops.id == %@", shopId];
```